# how to make the below query efficient to prevent timeout

Tags: sql

```
SELECT

case RTPD.Details3 when 'A' then '2' when 'R' then '1' else '3' end as DataTypeOrder,

RTPD.*

FROM RSTTransactionRptDetails RTPD with (nolock)

INNER JOIN RSTPayrollPrintParameters PP with (nolock)

ON RTPD.PayrollNumber = PP.PayrollNumber

AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod = PP.PayrunPeriod

AND RTPD.PeriodRunType = PP.PeriodRunType

AND RTPD.PayrunNo = PP.PayrunNo

WHERE RTPD.ReportCode = '0020'

AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod + RTPD.PeriodRunType +  convert(char,RTPD.PayrunNo) IN (@PayrunPeriods1)

AND RTPD.PayrollNumber IN (@PayrollNumber)

ORDER BY CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptPaygroup,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details51 END ASC,

CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptDept,'F')) = 'T' THEN RTPD.Details52 END ASC,

CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptCostcode,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details53 END ASC, RTPD.Details4 ASC,RTPD.Details48 DESC, RTPD.Details6 ASC
```

i have tried using a temp table as shown below, however the report shows no data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#transacRptDetails') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #transacRptDetails



SELECT
case RTPD.Details3 when 'A' then '2' when 'R' then '1' else '3' end as DataTypeOrder,RTPD.*
into #transacRptDetails
FROM RSTTransactionRptDetails RTPD with (nolock)
INNER JOIN RSTPayrollPrintParameters PP with (nolock)
ON RTPD.PayrollNumber = PP.PayrollNumber
AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod = PP.PayrunPeriod
AND RTPD.PeriodRunType = PP.PeriodRunType
AND RTPD.PayrunNo = PP.PayrunNo
WHERE RTPD.ReportCode = '0020'
AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod + RTPD.PeriodRunType +  convert(char,RTPD.PayrunNo) IN (@PayrunPeriods1)
AND RTPD.PayrollNumber IN (@PayrollNumber)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptPaygroup,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details51 END ASC,
CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptDept,'F')) = 'T' THEN RTPD.Details52 END ASC,
CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptCostcode,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details53 END ASC, RTPD.Details4 ASC,RTPD.Details48 DESC, RTPD.Details6 ASC
```

This query returns 2 million records in 4 mins and it usually causes timeout. How can I improve its performance because I have done what i could in the where condition. 
Also the table RSTTransactionRptDetails filters the most data (takes approx.5 mins to get 2 million records)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Chris Looking at syntax almost certainly SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Can you try filtering your table `RSTTransactionRptDetails` first, this will reduce your join result and make it lighter. Also instead of `select *` you can select just the fields you need.

```
    SELECT

case RTPD.Details3 when 'A' then '2' when 'R' then '1' else '3' end as DataTypeOrder,

RTPD.*

FROM (select * from RSTTransactionRptDetails WHERE RTPD.ReportCode = '0020'

AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod + RTPD.PeriodRunType +  convert(char,RTPD.PayrunNo) IN (@PayrunPeriods1)

AND RTPD.PayrollNumber IN (@PayrollNumber)) RTPD with (nolock)

INNER JOIN RSTPayrollPrintParameters PP with (nolock)

ON RTPD.PayrollNumber = PP.PayrollNumber

AND RTPD.PayrunPeriod = PP.PayrunPeriod

AND RTPD.PeriodRunType = PP.PeriodRunType

AND RTPD.PayrunNo = PP.PayrunNo

ORDER BY CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptPaygroup,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details51 END ASC,

CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptDept,'F')) = 'T' THEN RTPD.Details52 END ASC,

CASE WHEN UPPER(ISNULL(PP.CompAmdRptCostcode,'F')) ='T' THEN RTPD.Details53 END ASC, RTPD.Details4 ASC,RTPD.Details48 DESC, RTPD.Details6 ASC
```